# malloc always allocate the same address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I must do this:
Write the function `void AddName(char *Names[], int *size)` that takes an array of strings Names and a pointer of integer size.

- Checks if there is still enough space to store a new name.
- If there is, asks the user to input his name and store it in a huge array of char (100 char).
- Calculate the length of his name.
- Allocate a dynamic memory to store his name and store its location in one of Names
  indexes.
- Increment the size by one.

I have wrote this code but malloc always allocate the same address so the whole array Names become similar

```
int const MAX = 3;
void AddName(char *Names[],int *size)
{
    int tempsize = *size;
    char *s;
    if (tempsize > MAX)
        printf("\n ERROR: Array is full. Cannot add.");
    else
    {
        int i,len=0;
        char name[100];
        printf("Enter the name: ");
        scanf("%s",name);
        for(i=0; name[i]!='\0'; i++)
            len++;
        s = (char *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
        s = &name;
        Names[*size]=s;
        *size=*size+1;
        printf("\n Done.\n");
   }
```

}

Comment: `s = (char *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char)); s = name;` -- leak much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you allocate your memory, you store the address into the variable `s`.

Then you overwrite that value with the address of your `name` variable.

As a result, you will never know the allocated address, because you discarded it with the overwriting.

Comment: Thank you very much I really apreciate your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = &name;
```

This is wrong. You are obliterating the address that `malloc` just returned to you. What you want is to copy the contents of `name` to the memory position `s`. For that you need `strncpy`. Replace `s = &name` with:

```
strncpy(s, name, len);
```

Or, since you know that `strlen(name) == len`, and that you allocated enough memory, you can just use `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(s, name);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I really apreciate your help guys :)